# Return result using if statement with for loop in r

Tags: r

I would like to return the result in a vector based on the results of an if statement. My default value in the column would be "blank" and if both conditions are met `==FALSE` I would like the vector/cell to have "some text". Here is what I have so far:

```
COMP30$Test_3<-"blank"
matches<-list(c(COMP30$PMPI_Has_Plan,COMP30$PMPI_Is_Eligible,COMP30$Test_3))
for (match in matches){if (match[1]==FALSE & match[2]==FALSE){match[3]<-"some text"}}
```

After running, I am showing only "blank" even though there are instances of `==FALSE & ==FALSE`. Basically, either the condition is not evaluating or the result is not being returned. Just started learning R so I am not sure what I am missing. Thanks!

Comment: You are modifying the variable `match` in the loop that is erased at each iteration. Modify `matches` instead

Comment: Thanks. What code needs to change in order to modify matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can guess about your dataset. Please provide your data using `dput`.

Using vectorisation:

```
COMP30$Test_3<-"blank"
matches <- cbind(COMP30$PMPI_Has_Plan, COMP30$PMPI_Is_Eligible, COMP30$Test_3)
matches[!matches[,1] & !matches[,2],3] <- "Some text"
```

Or with a `for` loop:

```
matches <- cbind(COMP30$PMPI_Has_Plan, COMP30$PMPI_Is_Eligible, COMP30$Test_3)
for (k in 1:nrow(matches)){
  if (!matches[k, 1] & !matches[k, 2]){
    matches[k, 3] <- "some text"
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried both solutions and I am still not returning the expected result or "some text". For example, I modified the vectorisation solution slightly to say: matches[matches[,1]==TRUE & matches[,2]==TRUE,3]<-"some text" but I only return "blank". I modified solution 2 similarly ==TRUE with the same result. Any ideas? Is it a syntax issue perhaps?

Comment: @Chris2015 Is your column boolean or string ? Using `boolean == TRUE` is equivalent to `boolean` as it is alread true or false

Comment: I see. It is boolean. But if I use ==FALSE for both I still don't return a result. Does it matter that the first two columns in cbind are boolean and the third column is string?

Comment: First two are logical and the third is character.

Comment: Code working : `matches <- data.frame(a=c(T, F), b = c(T, T), c= "blank", stringsAsFactors = F);matches[matches[,1] & matches[,2],3] <- "Some text";matches`. Edit your question and give us `dput(head(matches))`

Comment: When i run the code and use dput(head(matches)) I get - structure(c("FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", 
"FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "Some text", 
"Some text", "Some text", "Some text", "Some text", "Some text"
), .Dim = c(6L, 3L))

Comment: That's if I use ==FALSE & ==FALSE. But, when I export the df to a csv file the "Some text" doesn't show. It only shows "blank"

Comment: Edit your question and provide `dput` before executing my answer please. Here there is no TRUE and TRUE

Comment: Right, there is no TRUE and TRUE in my df. There is only a FALSE and FALSE. I updated the question with FALSE and FALSE.

Comment: The dput(head(matches) returns the expected result which is great. But, when the data is written to csv I only see "blank". Very strange.

Comment: I suspect you don't write `matches` or modify it before export

Comment: That's it! Here is what I was missing COMP30$Test_3<-"blank"
matches <- cbind(COMP30$PMPI_Has_Plan, COMP30$PMPI_Is_Eligible, COMP30$Test_3)
matches[matches[,1]==FALSE & matches[,2]==FALSE,3] <- "Some text"
dput(head(matches))
COMP30$Test_3<-matches[,3]

Comment: Thank you so much! This has been unbelievably valuable.